# Use left join with two conditions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to implement a left join query wherein I have 2 conditions for it.

Below is my current query however it does not display the correct data. Am i doing it correctly?

```
  SELECT a.date_created, u.id, CASE WHEN a.status = 0 THEN 'Not Verified' ELSE 'Verified' END AS status 
  FROM affiliates a left join users u 
  ON  a.referral_code =u.ref_code OR  a.sub_referral_code = u.ref_code
  WHERE a.referral_code = 'Cx0mSU3axal8' OR  a.sub_referral_code = 'Cx0mSU3axal8';
```

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YTgQ.png)

[This must be the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoWs9.png)

Appreciate your help with this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some sample data, the current output and the expected output?

Comment: I have updated my post (added some pics for reference)

Comment: @giogio - Please add sample input data based on which you expect those results. Also, please don't post images. Post textual tables. Also it's not clear what the logic is behind your expected output. Is it the latest id?

Comment: To make this simple, I want to display the values where sub_referral_code or referral_code has a value of 'Cx0mSU3axal8'
I just used left join to grab the 'id' of each value from the other table where the ref_code under users is the same value on either referral_code or sub_referral_code under affiliates table. My apologies if I am making it complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed my problem. I just got a little confused with the condition part of the query.
Here is the working query I made:

```
 SELECT a.date_created, u.id, CASE a.`status` WHEN 0 THEN 'Not Verified' ELSE 'Verified' END AS `status` 
 FROM affiliates a left join users u 
 ON  a.email = u.email
 WHERE a.referral_code = 'Cx0mSU3axal8' OR  a.sub_referral_code = 'Cx0mSU3axal8';
```

Still thanks to all the feedbacks. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate what you mean not displaying the correct data? I would appreciate if you have sample data and the sample output that you are getting running the above query and what data you need to display.

Also, it would look cleaner if you do

```
CASE a.`status` WHEN 0 THEN 'Not Verified' ELSE 'Verified' END AS `status`
```

Can't really tell what is wrong with your query without seeing the data, the output and your desired output. Although your query tells me that you want to **display all** date_created from the affiliates where referral_code or sub_referral_code = 'Cx0mSU3axal8' whether referral_code or sub_referral_code exists in users table (left join) and id (output could be null if not found in affiliates table) from the users where ref_code = 'Cx0mSU3axal8'.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I have added some pictures on my post for the reference of the output it displays and the output I expect.

Comment: If only the status that are not correctly displayed you can try the query I posted.

Comment: I see you have duplicate records in the result are you sure it is left join that you need and not INNER JOIN?
it would be nice to see the users table record and include the referral and sub_referral in the sample.

Comment: I use left join since the data I want to display are coming from affiliates table, I just used left join just to grab the id of each id from users table

Comment: Can't really tell what is wrong without seeing the other table and the joining fields. I will assume that you know how LEFT JOIN works right?

Additionally, why do you think that only those 4 records should be the result?